# Android Can't download alpha app to nexus 7

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm testing an android application through the testing services on google play. Now I can't download it to a nexus 7. It says `Your device isn't compatible with the version! I've looked into the issue and it's apparently something to do with my permissions in my Manifest file, from what I've read it's to do with the camera feature. Now I don't use this feature on my applicaiton so I'm assuming it's because I'm using a different permission of feature on the application. Below is my manifest file:

```
<permission android:name="com.test.hearing.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.hearing.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Any help on this issue would be gladly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the `CALL_PHONE` permission. this will automatically require all devices to have a telephony feature.

add the following to your manifest.

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
  android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, I ended up just getting rid of the `CALL_PHONE` permission as I realised I didnt need it. Thanks for the help though